# Google autocomplete Component Restriction iOS

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, google-places-api

is there any equivalent of a component restriction for Google Places Autocomplete for iOS.

I have found a few wrappers that wrap around the webservice call but even those (wrappers) do not have the capability to filter by component Restriction in general it seems.

I'm looking for this to make sure the results are only for my country of interest.

http://goobbe.com/questions/8144956/google-places-autocomplete-api-country-restriction

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with the iOS SDK at the moment.

The `filter` parameter of `autocompleteQuery` allows you to filter by type  (it's a [GMSAutocompleteFilter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_filter.html) object), but currently offers no other filters.

For now you'll have to use the webservice (or a wrapper for the webservice that includes support for component restrictions).